# Varchar to timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to covert character varying to timestamp but i am getting an error like

```
ERROR: value for "YYYY" in source string is out of range
  Detail: Value must be in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647.
```

Query

```
select
TO_TIMESTAMP(lastmodifiedon ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:MS') lastmodifiedon 
from table1
```

Comment: So what is the value in the column?

Comment: its like '1580361463509'

Comment: You can't use `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:MS'` when your data is not in that format. That format string tells the function how to interpret the value in the first parameter.

Comment: then how do i declare ??

Comment: '1580361463509' isn't already a timestamp ? What output do you want ?

Comment: i need as timestamp field

Comment: Sry i need as date without unix timestamp

Comment: Getting error ERROR: function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1366 @Jim Jones

Comment: A note for future design decisions: don't store numbers in `varchar` columns, don't store timestamps as numbers, use `timestamp` instead. If you can still change your data model, then do it now

Answer (score 1):

Use the numeric `to_timestamp` function:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(lastmodifiedon::double precision / 1000) AS lastmodifiedon 
FROM table1;
```

Comment: While executing like the above i m getting an error like

Comment: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying / integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1394

Comment: Sorry, I missed the (strange) fact that the numbers are stored as strings.